# Dúvida sobre código de Listas em Python

Tags: python

será que alguém consegue me ajudar? Estou tentando imprimir a mensagem de 1º, 2º e 3º lugar na tela, entretanto não estou conseguindo. Alguém tem uma ideia?

```
lista = []
flag = False

for x in range(3):

    tamanho = len(lista)

    n = float(input("Digite um número inteiro: "))

    if( tamanho > 0 ):

        for y in range( tamanho ):

            if ( n >= lista[y] ):

                lista.insert( y, n )


                break

    if((x == 0) or (flag == False)):

        lista.append( n )

    else:

        flag = False

          print(lista)

          print("Primeira Posição:", "Segunda Posição:", "Terceira Posição:", )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A pergunta não ficou muito clara. O que seriam esses "1º, 2º e 3º lugar"? Seriam os números inseridos em ordem de inserção?

Caso sim, o seguinte código é funcional:

```
lista = []

for x in range(3):
    tamanho = len(lista)
    n = float(input("Digite um número inteiro: "))
    if((x < 3)):
        lista.append(n)

print("Primeira Posição: " + str(lista[0]) + " Segunda Posição:" + str(lista[1]) + " Terceira Posição:" + str(lista[2]))
```

Comment: Isso, eu preciso que apareça uma mensagem clara falando qual número ficou em qual posição!

Comment: Já me ajudou, obrigado mano :D